# Prove equation is differential at $a$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differential at $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $g(x) = c \cdot f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show, using the definition of differentiability, that $g$ is differentiable at $a$, and in particular, that $g'(a) = c  \cdot f'(a)$.

This should be an easy question. I'm guessing you use the limit 
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{ h}
$$
to solve it. Although I don't remember how to proceed. Can someone show me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we are given that $f$ is differentiable at $a$. We are not given that $f$ is differentiable everywhere. So, the best we can do is to show that $g'(a) = cf'(a)$.

We want to show that $\lim_{t\to0} \frac{g(a+t)-g(a)}{t}$ exists.

Notice that $$ g'(a) = \lim_{t\to0} \frac{g(a+t)-g(a)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0} \frac{cf(a+t)-cf(a)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0} c\frac{f(a+t)-f(a)}{t}$$

$$=c \lim_{t\to0} \frac{f(a+t)-f(a)}{t} = c f'(a)$$

Notice that everywhere that $f$ is differentiable, $g'(x) = cf'(x)$.

Comment: thank you! I have a similar question. If we let f be a differential equation such as f(x) =f(-x) for all x. Show with differentiability that f'(0) = 0.